# External drive doesn't boot on my computer, does when I boot in my college computer lab

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu onto an external HDD, and can boot into it from my school CS departments computers. It loads grub and I can select which drive want to boot to. However, I got home tonight and attempted to boot from the device and it loads straight to my Windows 10 installation. Grub doesn't show up at all.

A bit about my computer:
Its an MSI laptop with Windows 10(UEFI mode, but secure boot and fast boot disabled) and two internal drives. I've altered the boot order to boot from a USB hard disk first. I know that works, as I had been booting from a live Persistent USB for a while now. The external drive is ext4.

If any more details are needed, please ask.

Keep in mind when answering:
I'm very new to linux so I would appreciate as many details as possible.

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode as well? That's likely the problem, and then you'd need to reinstall it in UEFI mode. That, however, might make it unbootable of school PCs.

Comment: I would have to check, a friend of mine started the install as I had to attend class. But my guess would be that it was not installed in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ubuntu is installed in legacy-mode but legacy-mode is not enabled in your UEFI-BIOS Ubuntu will not boot, the BIOS will not find a bootable device and jumps to the next item in the boot-order-list. Try to enable legacy-boot-mode (also called CSM) in your UEFI-BIOS. You will find this option in the Boot-tab in UEFI-BIOS.

[image]

This example shows only UEFI-mode enabled.

Hope this helps to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm at work so I can't take the time to test this until lunch, but wont this also prevent me from loading into windows 10 unless I change it back? If so, i would probably rather just reinstall in UEFI mode as mentioned in the comments above. I will let you know the results of my test during lunch though. Thanks!

Comment: Enabling the CSM-module does not mean to disable UEFI. You may have three options, UEFI only, UEFI+CSM, CSM only.  You will see when you are in front of you laptop...

Comment: I have tried it, and unfortunately activating the UEFI-CMS option does not allow the device to boot, and the LEGACY option just takes me to PXE. Looks like im gonna just reinstall the OS

Comment: Then your install was definitely in UEFI-mode. You performed the install at the schools computer and Grub has been installed to the EFI-partition off school-computers hard-drive, that is why you couldn't boot at home. A new install is one solution, there are more possibilities.